# javascript length returning 3, should have 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to dynamically fill in the number of posts I have on my blog. I am using `.length` to get the number of posts. There are supposed to be eight posts, but it is returning one.
JS:

```
var nPosts = $(".l li ul").length; 
console.log(nPosts);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="l">
    <li style="list-style:none;">
        <h4>August 2015</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/08/difference-between-jquery-ui-and-bootstrap-icon" class="download" data-icon="download">The Difference between jQuery UI Icons and Bootstrap Glyphicons</a> - August 27</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/08/an-interesting-claim">An Interesting Claim</a> - August 28</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li style="list-style:none">
        <h4>September 2015</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/file-and-dir-same-name">How To Have a File and Directory with the Same Name</a> - September 1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/comparing-apples-and-windows">Comparing Apples and Windows</a> - September 4</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/remove-space-from-list-item">How to Remove the Extra Space from a List Item</a> - September 6</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/how-long-will-the-new-ip-address-last">How Long will the New IP Address Last?</a> - September 8</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/how-to-loop-a-youtube-video">How to Loop a Youtube Video (The Easy Way)</a> - September 20</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="list-style:none">
        <h4>October 2015</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/10/how-to-easily-download-anything">Two Ways to Easily Download Anything</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `var nPosts = $(".l li li").length; `

Comment: it must return 3. if you want to return all post you need to var nPosts = $(".l li ul li").length; 
console.log(nPosts);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are querying for the UL inside the LI elemts, and, in fact, you have 3 of them.

Try

```
var nPosts = $(".l .list-group li").length; 
console.log(nPosts);
```

Or, even better

```
var nPosts = $('.l .list-group-item').length;
```

Always avoid querying for tagnames in general use-cases, is always batter to query for classes inside ids (again, in general use-cases). This way you have much more controll and reusable logic.

```
$('#your-ID .your-classes')
```

Comment: Thanks... I hate it how they make you wait fifteen minutes before accepting an answer.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I get your point, but it's also a good mechanic to ensure that everybody has a chance to get accepted, not only the first person to submit an answer. There might be cases where a really really short answer solves your problem, but somebody else is writing a much deeper explanation and provides some examples, images etc., in which case the later one is obviously the one to be accepted.

Comment: No problem! I've edited the answer with another tip for you. Keep the good job, bro.

Answer (score 1):

This should neatly give you 8:

```
var nPosts = $(".list-group-item", ".l").length; 
console.log(nPosts);
```

OR more expressively:

```
var nPosts = $(".l").find("li.list-group-item").length; 
console.log(nPosts);
```

The reason your code failed is: `var nPosts = $(".l li ul")` is apparently returning your three `ul.list-group`s, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nPosts = $(".l li ul li").length; 
console.log(nPosts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="l">
    <li style="list-style:none;">
        <h4>August 2015</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/08/difference-between-jquery-ui-and-bootstrap-icon" class="download" data-icon="download">The Difference between jQuery UI Icons and Bootstrap Glyphicons</a> - August 27</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/08/an-interesting-claim">An Interesting Claim</a> - August 28</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li style="list-style:none">
        <h4>September 2015</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/file-and-dir-same-name">How To Have a File and Directory with the Same Name</a> - September 1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/comparing-apples-and-windows">Comparing Apples and Windows</a> - September 4</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/remove-space-from-list-item">How to Remove the Extra Space from a List Item</a> - September 6</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/how-long-will-the-new-ip-address-last">How Long will the New IP Address Last?</a> - September 8</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/09/how-to-loop-a-youtube-video">How to Loop a Youtube Video (The Easy Way)</a> - September 20</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="list-style:none">
        <h4>October 2015</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="blog/2015/10/how-to-easily-download-anything">Two Ways to Easily Download Anything</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```